# Is it okay to say "X has enriched the research of Y"?

Tags: word-usage

In my original sentence, X is the pluralism of a concept, and Y is an emotion.

My question is, simply put, can research be the object of enrich? I know that we can say "enrich our lives", "enrich our understanding of something", but is it correct to say "enrich the research of emotion"?

Comment: I'm being thrown off by your x and y.  Would these be fitting substitutions: "Women have enriched the research of love"?

Comment: I still don't understand.  What's X in the "research of emotion" example?